# Can I update weights of keras neural net only if validation improves?

Tags: validation, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backpropagation

I am training a neural network in keras and I reach a classical limit - my training accuracy improves with increasing epochs, but my validation accuracy decreases after 9 epochs (see figure).

[image]

I wonder if I can avoid the decrease of validation accuracy by doing the following: make the keras net only accept the changes to the weights after each epoch if the epoch led to an improvement of the validation accuracy, else reset to the state before the epoch? I assume that the validation is starting to diverge in a big part because after each epoch >9 the weights of the neural net diverge away from similarity to the validation data.

So, is my suggestion a good practice and can I achieve it in keras (are there callbacks or options that allow me to update the net only if the validation improved)?

Side question: Is my suggestion maybe violating the principle of "don't use your validation data for training"? Because I am making implicitly the performance of the neural net a function of my validation data.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the EarlyStopping callback?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks, yes, but EarlyStopping is not what I want. EarlyStopping would allow me to stop training after I have reached the best validation. Instead, I would like to continue training, but "force" my neural net to take a training path that is improving the validation accuracy

Comment: Its not about what you want, EarlyStopping exists because it is a well known practice, to stop training, because if you continue training, generally the validation loss keeps increasing, there no such path that improves the validation loss. Remember that you are training on the training set, so if you reject the weight update, then you are still training on the same dataset, you will en up in a never ending loop.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I understand what you mean. Though would I really "end up on a never ending loop"? Because every now and then, even in overfitted epochs, there are epochs with validation loss lower than the loss from the previous update. If I could update the neural net only for these epochs I might be able to push an improvement of the neural net generalization. If you know how to code this condition in keras, I would be happy to test it and publish my results here for other users.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I discovered just now the model_checkpoint call back, that does pretty much what I described above: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/ Do you have an opinion if it is a good practice to use it? I am asking because the Keras team has made it available, but you recommended me earlier to use EarlyStopping. Thanks!

Comment: No, this callback does not do what you wanted to do, the model keeps training with the same weights (not the best ones), it only saves the best model, it works similarly than EarlyStopping but without stopping.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the validation set is to give you an idea of the generalizability your model achieves by learning using the training data. You don't HAVE to have a validation dataset. If your validation data is a random sample of your training data, then your best bet is probably modifying your architecture.

In short, if you want your model to train based on your validation data, then train the model on the training set, then take the resulting model, and train it on the validation data (i.e. make the validation data the training data). This obviously defeats the point of having a validation set.

Comment: I discovered just now the model_checkpoint call back, that does pretty much what I described above: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/ Do you have an opinion if it is a good practice to use it? I am genuinely asking because the Keras team has made it available, but your opinion was that it defeats the point of having a validation set. Thanks for your opinion!